# MultiThreading error: no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hi guys I am new to c++ and working on getting multithreading working. 
What I am doing is trying to push 5 threads in a vector and make them multiply 2 matrices. However I keep getting this error. I know this will be flagged as a duplicate, but I am only asking because I couldn't really find another similar question in regards to threads.

The error I get based off the code below is the following:

Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'

Here is my Code

```
#include "matrices.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    CMatrix3 matrix1, matrix2, result;
    std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    matrix1.SetElement(0, 0, 2);
    matrix1.SetElement(0, 1, 2);
    matrix1.SetElement(0, 2, 3);
    matrix1.SetElement(0, 3, 1);
    matrix1.SetElement(1, 0, 0);
    matrix1.SetElement(1, 1, 0);
    matrix1.SetElement(1, 2, 2);
    matrix1.SetElement(1, 3, 5);
    matrix1.SetElement(2, 0, 1);
    matrix1.SetElement(2, 1, 6);
    matrix1.SetElement(2, 2, 2);
    matrix1.SetElement(2, 3, 0);
    matrix1.SetElement(3, 0, 0);
    matrix1.SetElement(3, 1, 2);
    matrix1.SetElement(3, 2, 0);
    matrix1.SetElement(3, 3, 2);

    matrix2.SetElement(0, 0, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(0, 1, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(0, 2, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(0, 3, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(1, 0, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(1, 1, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(1, 2, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(1, 3, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(2, 0, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(2, 1, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(2, 2, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(2, 3, 1);
    matrix2.SetElement(3, 0, 0);
    matrix2.SetElement(3, 1, 2);
    matrix2.SetElement(3, 2, 0);
    matrix2.SetElement(3, 3, 2);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(CMatrix3::Multiply, &matrix1, std::ref(matrix1), std::ref(matrix2), std::ref(result)));
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    result.display4by4(result);

    int h;
    cin >> h;
    return 0;
}
```

CMatrix3::Multiply is the entry point function of the class CMatrix3, it takes in 3 arguments matrix1, matrix2 and resultant matrix which is an identity matrix that will be the result of the two multiplied matrices. 
ie;this is what it looks like

```
CMatrix3 & CMatrix3::Multiply(const CMatrix3 & _rA, const CMatrix3 & _rB, CMatrix3 & _rResult)
```

If you can help I will be grateful.
Thanks

Comment: The question suggests a misunderstanding of what multi-threading is going to gain you. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Richard Hodges  It's just an excercise that requires me to use multiple threads to compute the multiplication of matrices and then time it to see  how fast it could be compared to just normal computation without threads.  However I haven't posted the extra bits of the code as its not relevant to the issue im having. The problem is I just cant get to use the thread to call the Multiply function correctly without the compiler errors popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi So I just fixed the error. The right code inside the for loop was supposed to be `threads.push_back(std::thread(CMatrix3::Multiply,std::ref(matrix1), std::ref(matrix2), std::ref(result)));` 
as opposed to `threads.push_back(std::thread(CMatrix3::Multiply, &matrix1,std::ref(matrix1), std::ref(matrix2), std::ref(result)));` I added in an extra parameter.
On top of that the reason it threw errors when I used an object as the second parameter after specifying the entry point was because the Multiply function was a static. I apologize and thank you guys for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Since c++11 (specifically the introduction of lambdas and range-based for), constructs such as bind, mem_fn and cref have become much less relevant.

You can achieve what you're trying to do like this (assuming I have correctly inferred the interface of CMatrix3):

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i<5; ++i)
{
    // static interface
    threads.emplace_back([&]{ CMatrix3::Multiply(matrix1, matrix2, result); });

    // or it could be one of these, depending on CMatrix3's interface:

    // threads.emplace_back([&]{ matrix1.Multiply(matrix2, result); });
    // threads.emplace_back([&]{ result = matrix1.Multiply(matrix2); });


}
for(std::thread& thread : threads) thread.join();
```

However, as the example stands, this would result in undefined behaviour since all five threads will race to overwrite the data in `result`.

Comment: how would you do it without the lamdas. Ie; by simply making a vector of 5 threads execute the multiply function??